# Automatically update variable data from the web in Python programming lanuage

Tags: python, python-3.x, forex

I have that little program

```
dol_rate = 0.84072
eur_rate = 1.18957

what = input("Select (A) DOL->EUR or (B) EUR->DOL: ")

if what == "A" or what == "a":
price1 = input("Enter a certain amount of US dollars: ")

doltoeur = int(price1) * dol_rate

print(doltoeur,"€")

etc...
```

And I want to know if there is any way to update the ***dol_rate*** and ***eur_rate*** variables automatically from the web with the current dollar and euro price.

Comment: currency != concurrency (replaced tag)

Comment: If you don't want to use an API, there's the option of [`forex-python`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/forex-python).